# DELETE sql statement in python

Tags: python, sql, string, postgresql

I have a postgres sql statement like so in python:

```
sql= """delete   
from {table}   
where person = '{Person}'   
AND name= '{Name}'   
AND sale= '{Sale}'""".format(table=TABLE,Person=PERSON,Name=NAME,Sale=SALE)
```

I am trying to account for NULLs in the WHERE clause. I want to do something like this:

```
    where person=Person if person is not None else person is Person   
AND <continue same expression for other fields>
```

Is there a way to incorporate that?

One way would be to create something like this:

```
sql="delete  
from {table}  
where "+ Person if Person is not None else person is Person + "  
AND "...<same expression>
```

Was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Read [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) and [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: If you use parameters instead of SQL string formatting, it will convert Python's Nones to Postgres' NULLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the database connector do your substitution.

```
where = []
vals = []
for k,v in ("person",Person),("name",Name),("sale",Sale):
    if v:
        where.append(f"{k} = %s")
        vals.append(v)
sql= f"DELETE FROM {TABLE} WHERE " + (" AND ".join(where))
conn.execute( sql, vals )
```

Comment: [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries): "

Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Never use Python string concatenation  even at gunpoint." Go to the link and see the correct way to do this.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver He is using parametrized queries provided by the SQL library - not % formatting. You can see that the SQL string (with placeholders!) and the vals are being passed separately to the `.execute()` call. This code is not vulnerable to SQL injection, unlike OP's or the other answer.

Comment: `TABLE = "table; select * from table" `.  `vals = ['adrian', 'klaver', 'sale']`. `cur.mogrify(sql, vals): "DELETE FROM table; select * from table WHERE person = E'adrian' AND name = E'klaver' AND sale = E'sale'"`. If you want to do this use [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver If you have your own solution, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver You are missing the point.  The database connectors do not do substitution of table names and field names.  That MUST be done in Python.  Fortunately, table names are not extracted from user input, so the injection thing is not a problem.

Comment: You have the right to be wrong.

Comment: That's a psycopg2 extension that is not generally available.  And it's still using Python substitution.

Comment: Yes there is [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html): `cur.execute(sql.SQL("delete from {} where person = %s and  name = %s and sale = %s").format(sql.Identifier('table; select from table')), vals) UndefinedTable: relation "table; select from table" does not exist
LINE 1: delete from "table; select from table" where person = E'adri...`

Comment: Read the link and learn. The point is there is a safer alternative and your solution is not a MUST.